# JavaScript / TypeScript - runtime code reconstruction, best approach

Tags: javascript, typescript

First of all, I would like to say sorry for that long question / problem description. On other hand, many of you like to know what is the discussed problem exactly related to ;) You can skip to last paragraph where the question is ;)

I am currently working on RMI (remote method invocation) for web workers / main ui thread for my framework (https://ajsfw.azurewebsites.net / https://github.com/atomsoftwarestudios). I need it to be possible to optimize performance of the main-ui thread (I wanted to avoid it in the beginning, but currently, its possible to notice "lagging" of animations when there are content-preparation tasks like model data processing,  view component state updates, virtual dom updates or others running in the background).

It includes ES6 class / ES5 "TypeScript class" "parsing" from the main-ui thread using toString() method including the class prototype tree. Once this is done and the code is grabbed and reconstructed the "source code" it passed over message channel (I call it RIB - remote invocation bus - as I have developed some network-like infrastructure to be possible to identify endpoints and invoke methods of deployed classes from whatever another endpoint) to another side. All this processes includes caching and reusing already parsed / reconstructed / instanced code so basically some optimizations of the RIB bandwidth and CPU resources usage.

Once the class is delivered to the worker and it is requested to be used from another worker or main-ui-thread it is instanced inside worker and the "proxy" class with same methods (but internally using the RMI infrastructure to call method on the opposite side and "await" the return value or exception) is instanced (or reused) on opposite side. There are two instancing strategies, so the class can be instanced or existing instance can be reused - that because I have adopted configurable .Net Core DI container with its 3 service scoping strategies) and i'll integrate it with all this machinery once this will be fully finished. Just to finish it - if the dependent class (object, service) is using the class in the same worker or the main-ui thread, the proxy is not used but rather direct reference is injected so the RMI is avoided). Of course, there will be a few limitations, but I don't want to discuss the full functionality here.

What I would like to discuss is related to parsing names and avoiding name collisions during reconstruction on the worker side while keeping the "user code" as clean as possible without need to push developers to add additional metadata to the code and ideally completely avoid string metadata to don't block anything imaginable (such as code minification - please don't say minifiers don't mangle class names under some circumstances ;), I hope still for full code minification so even this would be possible).

So basically, there are 3 types of information it is possible to get from the class definition. 2 of them can be parsed from its .toString() method (as .name is not 100% working on all platforms I am targeting).  Its a Non-FQDN runtime class name and some times FQDN, sometimes Non-FQDN of the class it extends (based on where the class is defined -> in case of TypeScript namespace and non-exported classes they are defined in anonymous closure so no way how to obtain the FQDN at all - sure, I can parse the source code, assign unique id to each anonymous closure ... uf, stop right now ;) ). Third information I can grab is the "unique class instance reference", basically the object representing the constructor function at runtime (of course, including its prototype chain) so it is possible to identify classes easily, reconstruct code, cache, parse, pass over, cache, reconstuct, instance... uf ;)

Only the one problem are class name collisions. That's because I want to keep same class names on other side (because of debugging, because of possibility of using instanceof, without need of any additional modification of the parsed code, whatever, take it as it is ;).

**Question comes now:**

So just to summarize. As mentioned, it is not possible to avoid class name collisions in particular thread (worker) while reconstructing them from main ui thread because it is not possible to collect the scope information in the main thread and reconstruct it on worker side. Actually, it is by parsing the source code file, but it would be too complex and rather it would be better to split code to modules and load them separately using XHR to workers, what I would like to avoid - it does not fit my framework concept at all, and this is what I want not to discuss here, because I have chosen this way, maybe it not correct, maybe its not how others are doing it, but I have chosen it ;) By the way, I am doing many things differently, especially tempting and hopefully you'll like it once I'll found a time to describe it to the documentation.

I would like to ask how you would solve a problem with class name collisions when creating them dynamically inside the web worker (using eval or new Function, does not matter) while keeping the same class names as in the main UI thread. I came with two solutions, one is more complex, second simpler, the problem is sill deep as classes should see another ones because they would require to extend them.

a) I would create a namespace (object) for each class and the I'll create a class inside. This would require to change "extends" statement, but it will probably require it anyway

b) I would create single namespace (object) where I'll put all classes and if the name collision will be detected I'll create a new namespace for the colliding class. Then I'll manage this in some way  with more code than in previous case

c) Is there any better way how to do it? With described requirements in mind i think

Thanks for reading and sorry for that long article / question

**EDIT:**

So, as it is impossible to find "service" internals when I want to avoid code parsing, in the end I'll probably go for the following solution (just example, in real it will look bit different):

```
// this will not never work as A is not exported so not possible to "decompile" and transfer to worker. So the condition will be that everything developer will need to use inside worker must be exported from the namespace (better said, accessible)

namespace NsA {

   class A {
   }

   export class B extends A {
   }

}

// this will work as its possible to grab all "static" dependencies:

namespace NsB {

   export const SOMETHING: string = "something";

   export class A {
      constructor() {
         console.log(SOMETHING);
      }
   }

   export class B extends A {
   }

}

// this will also work in case the previous namespace will be injected
// because A extends B from NsB.B. Notice, the NsC is children namespace
// of NsA
namespace NsB.NsC {

   export class A extends NsB.B {
   }

}
```

so if previous conditions will be met it will be possible to inject static dependencies to worker (worker is just instance of internal class which will communicate over RIB with worker and inject the code there - please note that there is running some "mini-OS" ;) in the worker already:

```
// namespace is basically the object holding everything
// parent namespaces is the complete namespace location like A, A.B, A.B.C
// this is necessary as it is required the correct run-time name of the
// namespace has to be determined and namespace tree reconstructed

// inject everything from namespace NsB. Parent is Window or DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope object respectively. This is necessary because in the following statement the NsB content will not be truly injected. In next step, the NS will be just created (if not exist previously) but it will be empty.
worker.injectNamespace(NsB);

// inject everything from NsC while keeping the namespace tree 
worker.injectNamespace(NsB, NsB.NsC);
```

in this case, I'll be able to locate the namespace in the parent namespace object and grab it's name while keeping the namespace tree topology same as developer defined.

After this, all static dependencies will be injected and it will be possible to instance any class with no doubt inside the worker. Also, class name collsions will be avoided.

Of course, I need to keep it maintanable and well understandable to developers so I need to think about the final design.

Comment: Too long, don't read. Your question really has nothing to do with RMI, and surely it could be expressed considerably more succinctly?

Comment: When I ask question in three words its wrong, when I describe the problem deeply its wrong too...

Comment: I am going for a different design based on modules now. This works but its not nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider saying the reason why you are deleting the answer. And at least notify author about it. Its hard to improve without feedback!

So another try:

So, I made some proof of concept. It is not ideal but without complete source code of modules being transferred it never will be.

See https://jsfiddle.net/1cy1vcsa/1/

its somehow commented, but will require some time to get in.

Serialization is traversing the namespace object and grabs everything possible from it.

```
 function stringifyObject(obj: any): string {

  // i prefer this way above lambda or anonymous.
  function replacer(key: string, value: any) {

             // enough to serialize function and classes on ES6+. ES5 requires bit more...
     if (this[key] instanceof Function) {
        // hopefully nobody will use __#UNSERIALIZE: identifier in his strings
        let s: string = __UNSERIALIZE + "<Function>" + this[key].toString();
        // here the ES5 code updater will be needed as it requires extensions to be passed as well
        // so basically, the stringifier of the prototype and __proto__ is needed
        return s;
     }

     if (this[key] instanceof Date) {
        return __UNSERIALIZE + "<Date>" + this[key].toString();
     }

     if (typeof(this[key]) === "object" && key !== "") {
          return;
     }

     return value;
  }

  return JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, 2);
```

}

Deserialization prepares namespaces and the closure code then calls the anonymous function with the closure code to setup the namespace.

```
// namespace unserializer
function reconstructNamespace(ns: any, serialized: string): void {

        // closure as TS is doing it will be needed
  let closure: string = "";
  let exports: string = "";

  // this always sucks... create a string representation of the closure as TypeScript is doing
  function stringifyObject(obj, isObject: boolean = false) {

     for (let key in obj) {

       let objKeyType: string = typeof(obj[key]);

                 if (objKeyType === "string" && obj[key].substr(0, __UNSERIALIZE.length) === __UNSERIALIZE) {

          let valType = obj[key].substring(obj[key].indexOf("<") + 1, obj[key].indexOf(">"));
          let val = obj[key].substr(obj[key].indexOf(">") + 1);

          switch (valType) {

             case "Date":
                closure += (isObject ? key + ": " : "var " + key + " = ") + "new Date(\"" + val + "\")";
                closure += (isObject ? ",\n" : ";\n");
                break;

             case "Function":
                closure += (isObject ? key + ": " : "var " + key + " = ") + val + "\n";
                break;

             default:
                 throw new Error("Invalid type");
                 break;

          }

         } else if (objKeyType === "string") {
          closure += (isObject ? key + ": " : "var " + key + " = ") + "\"" + obj[key] + "\"";
          closure += (isObject ? ",\n" : ";\n");
       } else if (objKeyType === "number" || objKeyType === "boolean") {
          closure += (isObject ? key + ": " : "var " + key + " = ") + obj[key];
          closure += (isObject ? ",\n" : ";\n");
       } else if (objKeyType === "object") {
          closure += (isObject ? key + ": " : "var " + key + " = ") + " {\n";
          stringifyObject(obj[key], true);
          if (closure[closure.length - 2] === ",") {
            closure = closure.slice(0, -2) + "\n}\n";
          } else {
            closure += "};\n";
          }
       }

     }

  }
```